# ASP.Net Browser Compatibility

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer

If I use IE to connect to my ASP.Net site and let the browser sit idle for a minute or so and then try to click on a new item, link, whatever, IE appears as though it's trying to load but never does anything.

If I connect to the site using Chrome and do the same thing Chrome pulls up the next item as expected with no delay. I've tried making changes to the web.config for sessionState and httpRuntime, to the ASP and pool settings in IIS, and I can't seem to do anything that fixes the problem in IE.

Is there another setting somewhere, perhaps in Windows to fix IE as this seems to a browser dependent issue and not related to the ASP site or IIS? I'm running out of ideas and most of the users will be using IE and not Chrome so it's not really a problem I can ignore.

Here's my web.config file if it helps:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data     source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    <add name="TaskSystemConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=REPORTSERVER;Initial Catalog=TaskSystem;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
      <sessionState timeout="3600"/>
      <httpRuntime executionTimeout="3600" maxRequestLength="2000000"/>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <membership>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <profile>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <roleManager enabled="false">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"/>
        <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID" validateRequest="false"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument>
  <files>
    <add value="Home.aspx"/>
  </files>
</defaultDocument>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
```

Comment: Ahh the irony. IIS can only serve pages to competing browsers. Have you tried making a VERY simple ASPX page just to make sure it isn't the page that is the problem?

Comment: chances are the issue is with the browser, not the website. chrome maybe aggressively caching and IE isn't.

Comment: which Windows version are you using? Could you please provide more informations about your environment (Windows Version, IIS Version, , browser version, etc). Are you trying to run in debug mode? Your application is using AJAX or regular postback?

Comment: Windows 7 and IE9 on my local PC and the server with the page on it is Windows 7 and IIS7. I'm not running in debug (to my knowledge anyway) and I can't answer the last question about AJAX or regular postback, but if I can't answer my guess is regular.

Comment: I tried creating another ASP.net site (the generic welcome to ASP.net project in VS2010) and deployed it and it seems to work fine in IE9. It doesn't fail after leaving it idle for a short time like the other site did. To further confuse (or perhaps clarify) matters, if I connect to the site from IE9 on the IIS server it doesn't seem to have issues with timing out on either site. So the issue seems to only be with IE9 from another PC accessing the site on the IIS server and I have no idea why that is. Any thoughts on where I might investigate from here?

Comment: I should mention I also tried Firefox against the site from a remote PC and it doesn't seem to have the timeout issue either. It really just appears to be a problem with IE9. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: So... after continued research and fiddling I found a Microsoft article that fixed the problem. Seems those special folks over at Microsoft decided a one minute timeout was an appropriate default... [link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/813827). Once I added the two necessary entries into the registry for KeepAliveTimeout and ServerInfoTimeout the problem went away. GRRRRRR!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... after continued research and fiddling I found a Microsoft article that fixed the problem. Seems those special folks over at Microsoft decided a one minute timeout was an appropriate default... http://support.microsoft.com/kb/813827. Once I added the two necessary entries into the registry for KeepAliveTimeout and ServerInfoTimeout the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

Could be something to do with database permissions. Have you tried specifying a SQL login in your connections strings? Can the account that is running IIS access these databases?

Also check your IIS settings to ensure that the authentication mode=Windows.

I have had issues with Windows authentication when i'm not using IE. For example, Chrome doesn't pass through the user identity and i have to enter my credentials each time i access the intranet.